# R, Pairwise comparison of random variable in mixed model

Tags: r, mixed-model, multiple-comparisons, random-variable, post-hoc

We measured temperatures of a pond repeatedly every day at each hour for a month at two different depths (i.e., top and bottom). We want to see if the temperatures at the top of the pond are significantly different from the bottom and if so at what hours. Initially I did a two-way anova in R:

```
aov.result <- aov(temp ~ depth * hour, data = pondtemp)
```

followed by post hoc tukey hsd test:

```
tukey.result <- TukeyHSD(aov.result)
```

The pairwise comparison of the depth*hour interaction term is what I need to see which hours have significantly different temperatures between top and bottom. This worked out well but someone pointed out that since it is a repeated measure it does not satisfy the assumption of independence. Therefore I tried using a linear mixed model. I took the depth as the fixed variable and figured the hour (since it has multiple observations in a month) should be the random variable:

```
pondmdl <- lmer(temp ~ depth + (1+variable|hour), data = pondtemp)
```

And used glht package for post-hoc:

```
summary(glht(pondmdl, mcp(depth = "Tukey")))
```

However, this does not allow me to do the pair wise comparison I want to do (i.e., comparing Top Hour 1 to Bottom Hour 0 -23)

I found one way by introducing an interaction factor:

```
pondtemp$depth.hour <- interaction (pondtemp$depth, pondtemp$hour)
```

and then using this in my model and glht function:

```
pondmdl <- lmer(temp~depth.hour + (1+depth|hour), data = pondtemp)
summary(glht(pondmdl, mcp(depth.hour = "Tukey")))
```

However, I'm not sure if I can allow fixed and random variables to interact like that and still use the same random variable in the random variable error term.

Please advise what is my best option.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using Generalized Estimating Equations (GEE) model a.k.a Marginal Multilevel Model (population averaged model). In R the GEE model can be found in the `geepack` package.

```
require(geepack)
pondtemp.gee <- geeglm(value~Hour*variable, id = Day, family = gaussian("identity"), data = data, corstr = "independence")
```

To see the model result:

```
summary(pondtemp.gee)
```

To do the post-hoc pairwise comaprison I used `lsmeans` function from the `lsmeans` package.

```
require(lsmeans)
pondtemp.posthoc <- lsmeans(pondtemp.gee, pairwise~Hour*variable, adjust = "tukey")
pondtemp.sum <- summary(pondtemp.posthoc)
pondtemp.contrast <- data.frame(pondtemp.sum$contrasts)
```

The pondtemp.sum$contrasts will contain the pairwise comparisons, which I wrote to an excel file and filtered for the comparisons I needed.

Comment: The `lsmeans` function is in the **lsmeans** package, not **userfriendlyscience**. FYI, the `adjust` argument has no effect as shown because there is no way to know which set of results to apply it to. The Tukey adjustment is already the default for the pairwise-comparison part, but it adjusts the entire family of comparisons. You might be able to get the comparisons you need without filtering via `pairwise ~ variable|Hour`, which will do a Tukey adjustment separately with each `Hour`

Comment: @rvl. Thanks for the comments. You are right, pairwise ~ variable|Hour would give me the pairwise comparison for each hour between the top and the bottom temperatures. However, I wanted to compare hour 1 of top depth with all hours of the bottom depth. The code I used will give me that.